What's the appropriate tense here?

It's Lara's birthday today and she (eat) a lot of cake!

I want to correct the verb "eat".
I thought of two answers 'will eat' and 'has eaten' Are both answers correct?

This is a question like "I own a pet (cat/dog) : choose the correct word."  Of course there is no correct word, it depends on what you want to say.  Almost any tense is possible here.

Thanks. Are there any other possible answers besides the present perfect, present continuous, and future simple?

It Lara's birthday...  she was eating  / she's been eating / she ate / she will have eaten / she's going to eat / she would eat /  she'd eaten  ...  pretty much any tense is possible.

I got it, thanks.

Both are correct, in the correct situation:

She has eaten a lot of cake.

She, in the past, ate the cake

She will eat a lot of cake.

She, in the future, will eat.

She is eating a lot of cake.

She eats the cake right now.  However, since "a lot" indicates something that requires time, using the progressive voice sounds more natural.
That is, that it happens today does not indicate whether it's past, present, or future, and that's what determines it.

Many thanks for helping.
